# Convert typedef struct from C++ to Python

Tags: python, c++, struct, typedef

I'm trying to port the following series of videos from C++ to Python.
You can find them in YT: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzGKCXSeHjDRSmpX9SmQ1fw/videos

The library with the 12000 words can be found here: https://pastebin.com/E5sDrFJ5

The idea behing is to build a solver for crosswords from scratch. So far, up to module 9, my Python code is equivalent to the C++ version:

```
def ToUpper(s):
    return s.upper()

class Library:
    def __init__(self):
        self.words = []
        self.counts = {}

    def IsWord(self, s): 
        for w in self.words:
            if s == w:
                return True
        return False

    def GetWord(self, i): 
        assert (i >= 0 and i < len(self.words))
        return self.words[i]

    def ReadFromFile(self, filename):
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
#                print(f"{line.rstrip()} ({len(line.rstrip())})")
                line = ToUpper(line)
                self.words.append(line.rstrip())    
        print(f"Read {len(self.words)} words from file '{filename}'")

    def ComputeStats(self):
        assert self.counts == {}
        for i in range(18):
            self.counts[i] = []
        for s in self.words:
            _len = len(s)
            if _len < 18: 
                self.counts[_len].append(_len)

    def PrintStats(self):
        print("Here are the counts of each word length")
        for k,v in self.counts.items():
            if k != 0:
                print(f"[{k}] {len(v)}")


class Grid:
    def __init__(self, n): 
        self.name = n 
        self.lines = []

    def rows(self):
        return len(self.lines)

    def cols(self):
        if self.lines == []: 
            return 0
        else:
            return len(self.lines[0])

    def LoadFromFile(self, filename):
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
#                print(f"{line.rstrip()} ({len(line.rstrip())})")    
                if not line.startswith('#'):
                    self.lines.append(line.rstrip())    

    def Check(self):
        for s in self.lines:
            assert len(s) == self.cols()

    def Print(self):
        print(f"Grid: {self.name} "
              f"(rows={self.rows()},"
              f" cols={self.cols()})")
        for s in self.lines:
            print(f"  {s.rstrip()}") 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lib = Library()
    lib.ReadFromFile("top_12000.txt")
    lib.ComputeStats()
    lib.PrintStats()

    print(lib.IsWord("DOG"))
    print(lib.IsWord("FUFFJFJ"))
    print(lib.IsWord("THANKS"))

#    grid = Grid("MY GRID")
#    grid.LoadFromFile('test')
#    grid.Check()
#    grid.Print()
```

The C++ version from the video is this one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <assert.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

string ToUpper(string s) {
  string s2; 
  for (char c : s) {
    s2.push_back(toupper(c));
  }
  return s2; 
}

class Library {
  public:
    bool IsWord(string s) const {
      for (string t : words) {
        if (s == t) {
          return true;
        }   
      }   
      return false;
    }   
    void ComputeStats() {
      assert(counts.empty());
      counts.resize(18);
      for (string s : words) {
        int len = s.length();
        if (len < 18) {
          counts[len]++;
        }   
      }   
    }   
    void PrintStats() const {
      cout << "Here are the counts of each word length:\n";
      for (int i=1; i<counts.size(); i++) {
        cout << "[" << i << "] " << counts[i] << "\n";
      }   
    }   
    string GetWord(int i) const {
      assert(i >= 0 && i < words.size());
      return words[i];
    }   
    void ReadFromFile(string filename) {
      ifstream f;
      f.open(filename);
      while (!f.eof()) {
        string line;
        getline(f, line);
        // cout << line << "  (" << line.length() << ")\n";

        if (!line.empty()) {
          line = ToUpper(line);
          int len = line.length();
          if (line[len-1] == '\r') {
            line = line.substr(0, len-1);
          }   
          words.push_back(line);
        }   
      }   
      cout << "Read " << words.size() << " words from file '"
          << filename << "'\n";
    }   
  private:
    vector<string> words;
    vector<int> counts;
};

struct Grid {
  Grid(string n) {
    name = n;
  }
  int rows() const { return lines.size(); }
  int cols() const {
    if (lines.empty()) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      return lines[0].size();
    }   
  }
  void LoadFromFile(string filename) {
    ifstream f;
    f.open(filename);
    while (!f.eof()) {
      string line;
      getline(f, line);
      cout << line << "  (" << line.length() << ")\n";

      if (!line.empty() && line[0] != '#') {
        lines.push_back(line);
      }
    }
  }
  void Check() const {
    for (int i=0; i<lines.size(); i++) {
      assert(lines[i].size() == cols());
    }
  }
  void Print() const {
    cout << "Grid: " << name
        << " (rows=" << rows()
        << ", cols=" << cols() << ")\n";
    for (string s : lines) {
      cout << "  " << s << "\n";
    }
  }
  string name;
  vector<string> lines;
};

int main() {
  Library lib;
  lib.ReadFromFile("top_12000.txt");
  lib.ComputeStats();
  lib.PrintStats();

  cout << lib.IsWord("DOG") << "\n";
  cout << lib.IsWord("FUFFJFJ") << "\n";
  cout << lib.IsWord("THANKS") << "\n";

  // Grid grid("MY GRID");
  // grid.LoadFromFile("test");
  // grid.Check();
  // grid.Print();
```

But I got stuck in lesson 9 because there is no "struct" data type in Python. In the video for lesson 9, this new structure "Word" was introduced. I highligthed the changes:

```
**struct Word {
  Word(string s) {
    word = s;
  }
  string word;
};
typedef vector<Word> Words;**

class Library {
  public:
    bool IsWord(string s) const {
      for (**Word w** : words) {
        if (s == **w.word**) {
          return true;
        }   
      }   
      return false;
    }   
    void ComputeStats() {
      assert(counts.empty());
      counts.resize(18);
      for (**Word w** : words) {
        int len = **w.word**.length();
        if (len < 18) {
          counts[len]++;
        }   
      }   
    }   
    void PrintStats() const {
      cout << "Here are the counts of each word length:\n";
      for (int i=1; i<counts.size(); i++) {
        cout << "[" << i << "] " << counts[i] << "\n";
      }   
    }   
    string GetWord(int i) const {
      assert(i >= 0 && i < words.size());
      return words[i]**.word**;
    }   
    void ReadFromFile(string filename) {
      ifstream f;
      f.open(filename);
      while (!f.eof()) {
        string line;
        getline(f, line);
        // cout << line << "  (" << line.length() << ")\n";

        if (!line.empty()) {
          line = ToUpper(line);
          int len = line.length();
          if (line[len-1] == '\r') {
            line = line.substr(0, len-1);
          }   
          words.push_back(**Word(line)**);
        }   
      }   
      cout << "Read " << words.size() << " words from file '"
          << filename << "'\n";
    }   
  private:
    **Words words**;
    vector<int> counts;
}
```

How should I proceed? Is it just to create a class "Word" like this?

```
  class Word:
      def __init__(self, n):
          self.word = n
```

I'm missing the typedef, because there are not such structures in Python. And then, how to use this new class in the "Library" class?

```
  class Library:
      def __init__(self):
         self.words = Words()
         self.counts = {}
```

Because this is giving me a TypeError:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'n'
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: C++ `struct`s are functionally identical to C++ `class`es except for default visibility of their members. Given that, what do you think the equivalent would be?

Comment: `struct` and `class` are equivalent, the only difference is that all members of a `struct` are `public` by default, and for `class` they are `private` by default. So it shouldn't matter for python, you can handle these like you would do with `class`es.

Comment: but what about the typedef? I read that this is just a shortcut for the class name, isn't it?